# Is it possible to run an Oracle script from Groovy?

Tags: oracle, groovy

Is it possible to run an Oracle script from Groovy using *groovy.sql.Sql*?    I don't think that reading the entire script into a String and then splitting it on the ';' semi-colon character will work because there are 'cursor', 'begin', 'for', and 'if' statements in the script which do not have semi-colons at the end.  Therefore, I believe I am seeking a way to run the script from Groovy via the JDBC driver.  Is that even possible or **am I required** to use the 'sqlplus' utility?

Comment: simply, the answer is no

Comment: just kidding, look at this: www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/groovy-1695411.html‎

Comment: Mostly depends on if you use use SQL (and PL/SQL) in that script or also SQL*Plus commands.

Comment: @MaziarBouali I fail to see what that link has to do with the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the easiest (and possibly only) solution is to call the `sqlplus` application:

Something like:

```
def proc = "sqlplus $username/$password@$db $scriptFilename".execute()
proc.consumeProcessOutput( System.out, System.err )
proc.waitFor()
```